# Can't install Flash Attention in Azure Databricks GPU (for Hugging Face model)

Tags: pytorch, azure-databricks, huggingface-transformers

I can successfully run the following code on a CPU cluster in Databricks.

```
import torch
import transformers
model =  transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "mosaicml/mpt-7b",
    trust_remote_code=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
)
```

On the CPU databricks cluster, I first installed Pytorch 2.0.1 ;Transformers 4.28.1 & einops 0.6.1.

However, the same Python code fails on a GPU cluster - with the following error:

`ImportError: This modeling file requires the following packages that were not found in your environment: flash_attn. Run pip install flash_attn`

I then tried to install the required package `pip install flash-attn` on the Databricks GPU cluster. (based on instructions [HERE](https://pypi.org/project/flash-attn/)

However, I have been unable to install Flash Attention on the GPU cluster.

On GPU I tried the following:

1. Attempted to install 'flash-attn' library on the GPU cluster. `pip install flash-attn` resulted in the following error:

```
Collecting flash-attn
  Downloading flash_attn-1.0.4.tar.gz (2.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.0/2.0 MB 28.1 MB/s eta 0:00:0000:010:01
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: torch in /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flash-attn) (1.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: einops in /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flash-attn) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flash-attn) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from packaging->flash-attn) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66 in /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torch->flash-attn) (11.10.3.66)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96 in /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torch->flash-attn) (8.5.0.96)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torch->flash-attn) (4.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99 in /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torch->flash-attn) (11.7.99)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99 in /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torch->flash-attn) (11.7.99)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch->flash-attn) (63.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch->flash-attn) (0.37.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: flash-attn
  Building wheel for flash-attn (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [317 lines of output]
      
      
      torch.__version__  = 1.13.1+cu117
      
      
      fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/flash_blocksparse_attn_interface.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/rotary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/flash_attn_triton_tmp_og.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/flash_blocksparse_attention.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/flash_attn_triton.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/bert_padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/flash_attn_triton_og.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/flash_attention.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/fused_softmax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/flash_attn_triton_varlen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/flash_attn_interface.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/flash_attn_triton_tmp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/attention_kernl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      copying flash_attn/flash_attn_triton_single_query.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/modules
      copying flash_attn/modules/embedding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/modules
      copying flash_attn/modules/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/modules
      copying flash_attn/modules/mlp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/modules
      copying flash_attn/modules/block.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/modules
      copying flash_attn/modules/mha.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/modules
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/utils
      copying flash_attn/utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/utils
      copying flash_attn/utils/generation.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/utils
      copying flash_attn/utils/benchmark.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/utils
      copying flash_attn/utils/distributed.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/utils
      copying flash_attn/utils/pretrained.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/utils
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/layers
      copying flash_attn/layers/rotary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/layers
      copying flash_attn/layers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/layers
      copying flash_attn/layers/patch_embed.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/layers
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/triton
      copying flash_attn/triton/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/triton
      copying flash_attn/triton/fused_attention.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/triton
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/losses
      copying flash_attn/losses/cross_entropy_apex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/losses
      copying flash_attn/losses/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/losses
      copying flash_attn/losses/cross_entropy_parallel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/losses
      copying flash_attn/losses/cross_entropy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/losses
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/ops
      copying flash_attn/ops/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/ops
      copying flash_attn/ops/layer_norm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/ops
      copying flash_attn/ops/gelu_activation.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/ops
      copying flash_attn/ops/rms_norm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/ops
      copying flash_attn/ops/fused_dense.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/ops
      copying flash_attn/ops/activations.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/ops
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/models
      copying flash_attn/models/gptj.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/models
      copying flash_attn/models/vit.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/models
      copying flash_attn/models/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/models
      copying flash_attn/models/llama.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/models
      copying flash_attn/models/gpt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/models
      copying flash_attn/models/bert.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/models
      copying flash_attn/models/gpt_j.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/models
      copying flash_attn/models/opt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/models
      copying flash_attn/models/gpt_neox.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/flash_attn/models
      running build_ext
      building 'flash_attn_cuda' extension
      creating /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      creating /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/csrc
      creating /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/csrc/flash_attn
      creating /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/csrc/flash_attn/src
      Emitting ninja build file /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/build.ninja...
      Compiling objects...
      Allowing ninja to set a default number of workers... (overridable by setting the environment variable MAX_JOBS=N)
      [1/9] /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc  -I/tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn -I/tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/src -I/tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/cutlass/include -I/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include -I/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-69bd3443-3436-4892-a827-1f1b494c1c35/include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/src/fmha_bwd_hdim32.cu -o /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/csrc/flash_attn/src/fmha_bwd_hdim32.o -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --compiler-options ''"'"'-fPIC'"'"'' -O3 -std=c++17 -U__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -U__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -U__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ -U__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --expt-extended-lambda --use_fast_math --ptxas-options=-v -lineinfo -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -gencode arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 --threads 4 -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=flash_attn_cuda -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
      FAILED: /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/csrc/flash_attn/src/fmha_bwd_hdim32.o
      /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc  -I/tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn -I/tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/src -I/tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/cutlass/include -I/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include -I/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-69bd3443-3436-4892-a827-1f1b494c1c35/include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/src/fmha_bwd_hdim32.cu -o /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/csrc/flash_attn/src/fmha_bwd_hdim32.o -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --compiler-options ''"'"'-fPIC'"'"'' -O3 -std=c++17 -U__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -U__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -U__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ -U__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --expt-extended-lambda --use_fast_math --ptxas-options=-v -lineinfo -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -gencode arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 --threads 4 -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=flash_attn_cuda -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
      In file included from /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/src/fmha.h:39,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/src/fmha_bwd_launch_template.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/src/fmha_bwd_hdim32.cu:5:
      /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.h:6:10: fatal error: cusparse.h: No such file or directory
          6 | #include <cusparse.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      In file included from /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/src/fmha.h:39,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/src/fmha_bwd_launch_template.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-nluf5697/flash-attn_79c1dfb03cc4482ba86c435b2db7a8b6/csrc/flash_attn/src/fmha_bwd_hdim32.cu:5:
      /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.h:6:10: fatal error: cusparse.h: No such file or directory
          6 | #include <cusparse.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.


......................................... [ removed middle of error message] 

          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/build.py", line 24, in run
          super().run()
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 79, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
          _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 346, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 843, in build_extensions
          build_ext.build_extensions(self)
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
          _build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 466, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 492, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 202, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 547, in build_extension
          objects = self.compiler.compile(
        File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 658, in unix_wrap_ninja_compile
          _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects(
        File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1573, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects
          _run_ninja_build(
        File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1916, in _run_ninja_build
          raise RuntimeError(message) from e
      RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> flash-attn

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Second, I tried the following:
2. updated torch library on GPU to version 2.0.1 (to match the successful approach on CPU) , tried again to reinstall flash-attn . This still didn't work.

My suspicion is that the code works fine on CPU cluster because it is NOT prepackaged with an earlier version of PyTorch. I install PyTorch 2.0.1 on Databricks CPU and it works fine. However, the GPU Cluster is preinstalled with an earlier version of Pytorch, and Flash Attention has not installed on GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely related to missing CUDA dependencies.

Please try restarting the cluster, running the following on a notebook cell and reinstalling `flash_attn` - and then give it another shot:

```
!wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/libcusparse-dev-11-7_11.7.3.50-1_amd64.deb -O /tmp/libcusparse-dev-11-7_11.7.3.50-1_amd64.deb && \
  wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/libcublas-dev-11-7_11.10.1.25-1_amd64.deb -O /tmp/libcublas-dev-11-7_11.10.1.25-1_amd64.deb && \
  wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/libcusolver-dev-11-7_11.4.0.1-1_amd64.deb -O /tmp/libcusolver-dev-11-7_11.4.0.1-1_amd64.deb && \
  wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/libcurand-dev-11-7_10.2.10.91-1_amd64.deb -O /tmp/libcurand-dev-11-7_10.2.10.91-1_amd64.deb && \
  dpkg -i /tmp/libcusparse-dev-11-7_11.7.3.50-1_amd64.deb && \
  dpkg -i /tmp/libcublas-dev-11-7_11.10.1.25-1_amd64.deb && \
  dpkg -i /tmp/libcusolver-dev-11-7_11.4.0.1-1_amd64.deb && \
  dpkg -i /tmp/libcurand-dev-11-7_10.2.10.91-1_amd64.deb
```

**Update** - added both the init script and general instructions as part of this repo: https://github.com/rafaelvp-db/databricks-llm-prompt-engineering

Comment: Yes, this model needs these NVIDIA libraries beyond what the CUDA drivers provide. After this, you also want to %pip install ninja (for faster builds of the next deps), and then %pip install einops flash-attn==v1.0.3.post0 triton==2.0.0.dev20221202 That's what you need as of today at least; later readers may find you need later library versions for MPT

Comment: Many thanks. I encountered the following error, do you know how to resolve this? Apologies for basic question (I'm new to GPUs). `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcublas-dev-11-3:
 libcublas-dev-11-3 depends on libcublas-11-3 (>= 11.5.1.109); however:
  Package libcublas-11-3 is not installed.`

Comment: Hey @Padhraig - can you just confirm which DBR version you're using? I've just tested this on DBR ML 13.0 and it works. Do you perhaps have some customization / init script / different package version?

Comment: Sorry, just missed the part where you say you're using PyTorch 2.1. Can you try again with a fresh installation of DBR ML 13.0 (without upgrading PyTorch version)?

Comment: You could also try with PyTorch 2.1, but in this case you would need to replace the Cuda version with a newer one (most likely 12.1)

Comment: Thanks. Your approach works, with fresh installation of DBR ML 13.0 without upgrading pytorch. I accepted your answer above.

Comment: Awesome, great to know!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! I suspect this is CUDA shenanigans. Does `!nvcc --version` yield a version higher than 11.4? According to the docs for `flash-attn` (https://pypi.org/project/flash-attn/), you need a CUDA more than or equal to than 11.4.

Comment: Thank you Brock! After running `!ncvv --version` in my Databricks notebook I see `ncvv: command not found`. When I run `nvidia-smi` I see: `CUDA Version: 11.4` 
And when I run `print(torch.__version__)` I see `1.13.1+cu117`
So it seems that PyTorch and CUDA meet the minimum requirements for FlashAttention. However, there is reference to both CUDA 11.4 and 11.7 above, perhaps some conflict here?

Comment: @Padhraig My answer had a small typo, it's `nvcc`, not `ncvv`. I've edited it to match. So your version of torch is actually expecting CUDA 11.7. I would recommend either upgrading your CUDA or downgrading your `torch`. A little confusing considering the torch installation should come with the CUDA binaries in the first place though, maybe the CUDA installed on your machine is messing with it. Or maybe it's something to do with Databricks, maybe they don't put the CUDA binaries in the torch package.

Comment: Thanks again Brock. I ran `pip install torch==1.12.1`. Now I see `torch.__version__` is `1.12.1+cu102`. CUDA version is still 11.4. When I installed torch 1.12.1 it showed: `Attempting uninstall: torch. Found existing installation: torch 1.13.1 Not uninstalling torch at /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages, outside environment .........     Can't uninstall torch. No files were found to uninstall.` Still getting the original error message for `pip install flash-attn`. It might be a databricks issue.

Comment: Update - tried with T4 GPU (supported by 'flash-attn' as per their documentation). Previously tried with V100 GPU which is not supported. The same error arose, so this is not the root cause.

Comment: @Padhraig can you do the pip install bit like this: `%pip install torch==...`? When I try with torch 1.13 and CUDA 11.7 it works

Comment: @Padhraig just a heads up - also for those who come across this question - starting from DB ML Runtime 13.2 there's not need to install these addons :)